# Determine if V is a Vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, axioms

[Set V with addition and multiplication defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMRQ9.png)

if u + v = 3n + r. Does that mean u = 3n and v = r?

To prove this is a vector space, you have to use the Axioms of a vector space. I know the axioms but I do not know how to show they are satisfied.

[A1] Closure. The set is closed under addition.

I am confused as how you would show this.

3n is an element of N_0
 and r is an element of V. Therefore 3n + r is in V. Is this correct?

Comment: Isn’t a vector space supposed to be over a field?

Comment: Is the vector space in this question not over a vector field?

Answer (score 1):

Closure is obvious because of the table given in lines 5-7 of the explanations.

This question is strange because in the usual definition of a vector space, the set of scalars is supposed to be a field. Here, $\mathbb N_0 = \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ is far from being a field because, for instance, nonzero elements do not have any inverse for addition:
if $n\in \mathbb N$, there is no element $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $n+k=0$. So, the formal answer to the question (at least with the usual definition of a vector space) is *no*: V is not a vector space.

In fact, your example is a strange variation on the field with three elements, seen as a vector space of dimension one on itself.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand.

Comment: I tried to give some more details.

Comment: Thanks, I do understand this but the next question is 'find all the subspaces for v' which only makes sense if v was a vector space. So I am assuming v has to be a vector space.

Comment: Maybe you are (or your teacher is) working with an exotic definition of vector space in which the set of scalars would not be required to be a field. This would be a bad choice of terminology in my opinion, but it is possible.